# How to merge or join data which have the same data with SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge

How to merge or join the data which has the same information to one row as image below.

[image]

**SQL:**

```
SELECT C.[LocationCode]
    ,C.[PartNumber]
    ,C.[WorksOrderNumber]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), C.[BatchQuantity]) AS 'MAC_Outstanding'
FROM CUSTOMER_MN C
WHERE C.[LocationCode] = 'P1'

SELECT R.[LocationCode]
    ,R.[PartNumber]
    ,R.[WorksOrderNumber]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), R.[PlannedQuantity] - R.[ActualQuantity]) AS 'ASY_Outstanding'
FROM CUSTOMER_RH R
WHERE R.[LocationCode] = 'P1'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to merge data use `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT C.[LocationCode]
    ,C.[PartNumber]
    ,C.[WorksOrderNumber]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), C.[BatchQuantity]) AS 'MAC_Outstanding'
FROM CUSTOMER_MN C
WHERE C.[LocationCode] = 'P1'

UNION ALL

SELECT R.[LocationCode]
    ,R.[PartNumber]
    ,R.[WorksOrderNumber]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), R.[PlannedQuantity] - R.[ActualQuantity]) AS 'ASY_Outstanding'
FROM CUSTOMER_RH R
WHERE R.[LocationCode] = 'P1'
```

In order to merge data use following query:

```
Select * 
From (
    SELECT C.[LocationCode]
        ,C.[PartNumber]
        ,C.[WorksOrderNumber]
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), C.[BatchQuantity]) AS 'MAC_Outstanding'
    FROM CUSTOMER_MN C
    WHERE C.[LocationCode] = 'P1')z1

Left Join (
    SELECT R.[LocationCode]
        ,R.[PartNumber]
        ,R.[WorksOrderNumber]
        ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), R.[PlannedQuantity] - R.[ActualQuantity]) AS 'ASY_Outstanding'
    FROM CUSTOMER_RH R
    WHERE R.[LocationCode] = 'P1'
    )z2 On Z1.LocationCode = Z2.LocationCode, Z1.PartNumber = Z2.PartNumber and Z1.WorkOrderNumber = z2.WorkOrderNumber
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `join`?

```
SELECT C.[LocationCode]
    ,C.[PartNumber]
    ,C.[WorksOrderNumber]
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), C.[BatchQuantity]) AS 'MAC_Outstanding'
    ,CONVERT(DECIMAL(18,0), R.[PlannedQuantity] - R.[ActualQuantity]) AS 'ASY_Outstanding'
FROM CUSTOMER_MN C
JOIN CUSTOMER_RH R ON C.LocationCode = R.LocationCode AND C.Partnumber = R.Partnumber AND C.WorksOrderNumber = R.WorksOrderNumber
WHERE C.[LocationCode] = 'P1'
```